# List category names from database as menu

Tags: php, sql, list, menu

I want to create a menu from category names in database, so far I have this:

```
$list  = "SELECT category FROM posts";
$rlist = mysql_query($list) or die(mysql_error());

while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rlist)) 
 { 
 $catname = $rows['category'];
 echo '<li><a href="' . $url . '/index.php?cat=' . $catname . '">' . $catname . '</a></li>';
}
```

Which lists everything but I need to make each only list once so its a menu.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT category FROM posts`

Comment: Can you re-phase the second part of your question by editing it. It doesn't really make sense so its hard to help you out. Including the HTML you have and the HTML you want might be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM posts;
```

And assuming you want them ordered

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM posts ORDER BY category ;
```

Comment: @Dizzi Make sure you click the check box to accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your category to be only listed once, you chould change your query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM POSTS
```